# Is file access in unit tests bad?

Tags: unit-testing

When writing unit tests that deal with XML (e.g. test a class that reads/generates XML) I used to write my asserted outcome XML-String / my input XML String in separate files right next to my unit test. Let's say I have a class "MyTransformer" that transformes one XML format into another. Then I would create three files all in the same package:

- MyTransformerTest.java
- MyTransformerTestSampleInput.xml
- MyTransformerTestExpectedOutput.xml

Then my assertion might look like this (simplified pseudo code for reasons of simplicity):

```java
Reader transformed = MyTransformer.transform(getResourceAsStream("MyTransformerTestSampleInput.xml")));
Reader expected = getResourceAsStream("MyTransformerTestExpectedOutput.xml");
assertXMLEqual(expected, transformed);
```

However a colleague told me that the file access that I have in this unit test is unacceptable. He proposed creating a literal string constant (private static final String) containing my XML file contents, possibly in a separate groovy class because of the benefit of multi line strings rather than writing the XML file into files.

I dislike the idea of the literal string constants, because even if I have multi line strings in groovy, I still loose syntax highlighting and all the other helpful features of my XML editor that tell me right away if my XML has syntax errors etc.

What do you think? Is the file access really bad? If so: Why? If not why is it ok?

Comment: You can hava test/resources folder where you hold all this stuff. It would be better if you have some kind of XML template in there which you could next parametrized. Little XML string or use groove to represent string not good idea (in my opinion...) Maybe mock will be helpful it depends

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two problems with files in unit tests:

- **they slow down the testing cycle.** You may have thousands of unit tests which, preferably, get run on every build - so they should be as fast as possible. If you can  speed them up (eg, by getting rid of I/O operations) you'd want to do that. Surely it's not always feasible, so you normally separate out the "slow" tests via [NUnit [Category]](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=category&r=2.2) or something similar - and then run those special tests less frequently - say, only on Nightly builds.
- **they introduce additional dependencies**. If a test requires a file, it will fail not only when the logic behind the test is wrong, but also when the file is missing, or test runner doesn't have read permissions etc. Which makes debugging and fixing not so pleasing!

That said, I won't be too strict about not using files in the tests. If possible, try to avoid them but don't get mad. Make sure you consider maintainability vs speed - the cleaner the test, the easier it will be to fix and understand it later.

Answer (score 0):

If your Unit Tests access the files to feed the fake test data into the System Under Test, so you can run tests, that's not a problem. That actually helps your to have wider variety of test data to exercise within the system under test.

However if your System Under Test access the file system, when executing from the a test, that's not a Unit Test. That's an Integration Test. This is because you are accessing cross cutting concerns such as file system, and they cannot categorised as Unit Tests.

You would really isolate/fake out the file access and test the behaviour of your code (if any), using Unit Tests. They are faster and easier to run. It gives your a pin point feedback if written correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In these cases, I have a unit test that uses an internal representation of the file, which is a string literal in this case.

I also will have an Integration Test, to test the code works correctly when writing to the file.

So it is all down to the Unit / Integration test definitions. Both are valid tests, just depends which test you are writing at the time.

Answer (score 0):

If the xml is more readable, or easier to work with in a file, and you have a lot of these tests, I would leave them.

Strictly speaking, unit tests should not use the file system because it is slow. However, readability is more important. XML in a file is easier to read, and can be loaded in an XML friendly editor.

If the tests take to long to run (cause you have a lot of them), or your colleagues complain, move them to integration tests.

If you work in Windows and LINUX, you have to be careful that the files are picked up by your build server.

There are no perfect answers.